# Pandas str.extract: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to repurpose this function from using `split` to using `str.extract` (regex) instead.

```
def bull_lev(x):
    spl = x.rsplit(None, 2)[-2].strip("Xx")
    if spl.str.isdigit():
        return "+" + spl + "00"
    return "+100"

def bear_lev(x):
    spl = x.rsplit(None, 2)[-2].strip("Xx")
    if spl.str.isdigit(): 
        return "-" + spl + "00"
    return "-100"

df["leverage"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: bull_lev(x)
    if "BULL" in x else bear_lev(x) if "BEAR" in x else "+100"
```

---

I am using `pandas` for `DataFrame` handling:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL AXP UN X3 VON", "BEAR ESTOX 12x S"], columns=["name"])
```

Desired output:

```
name                    leverage
"BULL AXP UN X3 VON"    "+300"
"BEAR ESTOX 12x S"      "-1200"
```

---

Faulty regex attempt for `"BULL"`:

```
def bull_lev(x):
    #spl = x.rsplit(None, 2)[-2].strip("Xx")
    spl = x.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip("x")
    if spl.str.isdigit():
        return "+" + spl + "00"
    return "+100"

df["leverage"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: bull_lev(x)
    if "BULL" in x else bear_lev(x) if "BEAR" in x else "+100")
```

Produces error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toolkit.py", line 128, in <module>
    df["leverage"] = df["name"].map(lambda x: bull_lev(x)
  File "/Python/Virtual/py2710/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2016, in map
    mapped = map_f(values, arg)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1061, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:58435)
  File "toolkit.py", line 129, in <lambda>
    if "BULL" in x else bear_lev(x) if "BEAR" in x else "+100")
  File "toolkit.py", line 123, in bear_lev
    spl = x.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip("x")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I am assuming this is due to `str.extract` capturing a list while `split` works directly with the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the positive case using the following:

```
In [150]:
import re
df['fundleverage'] = '+' + df['name'].str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('X') + '00'
df

Out[150]:
                 name fundleverage
0  BULL AXP UN X3 VON         +300
1    BULL ESTOX X12 S        +1200
```

You can use `np.where` to handle both cases in a one liner:

```
In [151]:
df['fundleverage'] = np.where(df['name'].str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('X').str.isdigit(),  '+' + df['name'].str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('X') + '00', '+100')
df

Out[151]:
                 name fundleverage
0  BULL AXP UN X3 VON         +300
1    BULL ESTOX X12 S        +1200
```

So the above uses the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html#pandas.Series.str.strip), [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) and [`isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html#pandas.Series.str.isdigit) to achieve what you want.

**Update**

After you changed your requirements (which you should not do for future reference) you can mask the df for the bull and bear cases:

```
In [189]:
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL AXP UN X3 VON", "BEAR ESTOX 12x S"], columns=["name"])
bull_mask_name = df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('bull', case=False), 'name']
bear_mask_name = df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('bear', case=False), 'name']
df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('bull', case=False), 'fundleverage'] = np.where(bull_mask_name.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('X').str.isdigit(),  '+' + bull_mask_name.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('X') + '00', '+100')
df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('bear', case=False), 'fundleverage'] = np.where(bear_mask_name.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('x').str.isdigit(),  '-' + bear_mask_name.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE).str.strip('x') + '00', '-100')
df

Out[189]:
                 name fundleverage
0  BULL AXP UN X3 VON         +300
1    BEAR ESTOX 12x S        -1200
```